# Magento 2: Override html classes in account dashboard navigation

Tags: magento2, php, customer-account

I want to change classes **nav item** with my own classes for customer account dashbaord navigation. What's the best way to do this?

This is the core file which creates the classes.

**Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current.php**

```
        if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    $highlight = '';

    if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
        $highlight = ' current';
    }

    if ($this->isCurrent()) {
        $html = '<li class="nav item current">';
        $html .= '<strong>'
            . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()))
            . '</strong>';
        $html .= '</li>';
    } else {
        $html = '<li class="nav item' . $highlight . '"><a href="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getHref()) . '"';
        $html .= $this->getTitle()
            ? ' title="' . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getTitle())) . '"'
            : '';
        $html .= $this->getAttributesHtml() . '>';

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '<strong>';
        }

        $html .= $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()));

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '</strong>';
        }

        $html .= '</a></li>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code

```
if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    $highlight = '';

    if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
        $highlight = ' current';
    }

    if ($this->isCurrent()) {
        $html = '<li class="custom current">';
        $html .= '<strong>'
            . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()))
            . '</strong>';
        $html .= '</li>';
    } else {
        $html = '<li class="custom' . $highlight . '"><a href="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getHref()) . '"';
        $html .= $this->getTitle()
            ? ' title="' . $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getTitle())) . '"'
            : '';
        $html .= $this->getAttributesHtml() . '>';

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '<strong>';
        }

        $html .= $this->escapeHtml((string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($this->getLabel()));

        if ($this->getIsHighlighted()) {
            $html .= '</strong>';
        }

        $html .= '</a></li>';
    }

    return $html;
```

[image]

Comment: @Sondre is that working for you ?